# firebase functions:secrets:set is not a Firebase command

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I am using cloud functions and would like to use Secret Manager to protect api keys for some services. Following the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#create-secret) , I tried using the command:

```
firebase functions:secrets:set STRIPE_TEST
```

but I received the following error:

```
Error: functions:secrets:set is not a Firebase command. Did you mean functions:config:set?
```

I want use secrets, not config that is not recommended

Comment: can you tell the version of firebase function and firebase tools? it seems to be an version issue.

Comment: Hi @DivyaniYadav, yes , it's a problem of firebase tools version, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem on `firebase-tools` version 10.1.2. There's currently a newer version 11.1.0 available but I was having trouble upgrading or even uninstalling:

```
$ firebase --version
10.1.2
$ npm i -g firebase-tools
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
...
$ firebase --version
10.1.2
$ npm uninstall --location=global firebase-tools
up to date, audited 1 package in 52ms
$ firebase --version
10.1.2
```

I figured out I could successfully uninstall `firebase-tools` with `curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash` then I reinstalled it with `npm i --location=global firebase-tools`

That finally upgraded `firebase --version` to 11.1.0 which fixed `firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME` for me.

Comment: Hi @cgenco,  I had the same version of firebase-tools and I followed your same steps. Now the command works, thank you =)

Comment: Close your terminal and open a new one after running `npm i -g firebase-tools`. At least that worked for me